# Optimizing Short Circuit Detection in Large Atom Cell: Seeking execution time improvement

Tags: java, algorithm, performance, data-structures

Context:
I am working on a simulation problem involving an n x n matrix that represents atoms. Each atom can be either a conductor or not. The simulation involves transmuting non-conductive atoms into conductive ones and determining if this creates a "short circuit," defined as a connection of conductive atoms from the top to the bottom of the matrix

Problem:
The current algorithm for detecting short circuits is inefficient for large matrices (e.g., 2000x2000). I need to optimize it to reduce execution time, ideally to O(logn) or better.

Actual code for the cell:

```
    public class CeldaAvanzada implements Celda {
private DisjointSet disjointSet;
private int n;
private boolean cortocircuito;
private boolean[][] esConductor;
private int lastI,lastJ;
private int[] transmutadosSuperior;
private int[] transmutadosInferior;
private int contadorSuperior ;
private int contadorInferior ;





public void Inicializar(int n) {
    this.n = n;
    disjointSet = new DisjointSet(n * n);
    esConductor = new boolean[n][n];
    cortocircuito = false;
    transmutadosSuperior = new int[n]; // Tamaño máximo igual al número de columnas
    transmutadosInferior = new int[n];
    contadorSuperior = 0;
    contadorInferior = 0;
  
    
}

public void RayoCosmico(int i, int j) {
  
    if (!esConductor[i][j]) {
        esConductor[i][j]=true;
        if (i == 0) {
            transmutadosSuperior[contadorSuperior++] = j;
        } else if (i == n - 1) {
            transmutadosInferior[contadorInferior++] = j;
        }
        lastI=i;
        lastJ=j;
        
        
        uniteAdjacentAtoms(i, j);
        
    }
}



public boolean Cortocircuito() {
return cortocircuito;
```

}

```
    private void uniteAdjacentAtoms(int i, int j) {
int index = getKey(i, j);

int[] dx = {-1, -1, -1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1};
int[] dy = {-1, 0, 1, -1, 1, -1, 0, 1};

for (int k = 0; k < dx.length; k++) {
    int ni = i + dx[k];
    int nj = j + dy[k];
    if (ni >= 0 && ni < n && nj >= 0 && nj < n && esConductor[ni][nj]) {
        disjointSet.union(index, getKey(ni, nj));

    }
}
actualizarBanderasDeConexion(index);
```

}

```
private void actualizarBanderasDeConexion(int indice) {
boolean conexionSuperior = false;

// Verificar si es necesario ejecutar el bucle
if (contadorSuperior > 0) {
    for (int k = 0; k < contadorSuperior; k++) {
        int indiceSuperior = getKey(0, transmutadosSuperior[k]);
        if (disjointSet.isConnected(indice, indiceSuperior)) {
            conexionSuperior = true;
            break; // Salir del bucle al encontrar una conexión
        }
    }
}

if (conexionSuperior && contadorInferior > 0) {
    for (int l = 0; l < contadorInferior; l++) {
        int indiceInferior = getKey(n - 1, transmutadosInferior[l]);
        if (disjointSet.isConnected(indice, indiceInferior)) {



            cortocircuito = true;
            break; // Salir del bucle al encontrar una conexión
        }
    }
}
```

}

```
private int getKey(int i, int j) {
    return i * n + j;
}
@Override
public String toString() {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            if (i == lastI && j == lastJ) {
                sb.append("*"); // Marcamos el último átomo afectado
            } else {
                sb.append(esConductor[i][j] ? "X" : "."); // X para conductores, . para no conductores
            }
        }
        sb.append("\n");
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Implementation of disjoint sets

```
    class DisjointSet {
private int[] parent;
private int[] rank;

public DisjointSet(int size) {
    parent = new int[size];
    rank = new int[size];
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        parent[i] = i;
        rank[i] = 0; // Inicializar rangos en 0
    }
}

public int find(int i) {
    if (parent[i] != i) {
        parent[i] = find(parent[i]); // Compresión de caminos
    }
    return parent[i];
}

public void union(int x, int y) {
    int rootX = find(x);
    int rootY = find(y);

    if (rootX != rootY) {
        if (rank[rootX] < rank[rootY]) {
            parent[rootX] = rootY;
        } else if (rank[rootX] > rank[rootY]) {
            parent[rootY] = rootX;
        } else {
            parent[rootY] = rootX;
            rank[rootX]++;
        }
    }
}
public boolean isConnected(int x, int y) {
    return find(x) == find(y);
}
```

}
}

Current Strategy:
I use a disjoint set structure to handle the union and search of connected atoms. When an atom is transmuted into a conductor, I update the disjoint sets and check for a short circuit. However, the verification of the short circuit, which requires checking all atoms in the top and bottom rows for each transmutation, has become a bottleneck.

Question:
How can I optimize this process, especially the short circuit detection? Are there more suitable data structures or algorithms for this type of problem that can improve efficiency, particularly for large matrices?

Note: No import statements can be used in this solution. Any data structure required for the algorithm must be defined manually. Any existing structure can be modified or replaced to improve efficiency.

Comment: My instinct is that you might be best off with a colouring algorithm so setting conducting atoms that touch top or bottom to distinct values. Then when you are about to change the state of an insulating atom you only have to look at its nearest neighbours to determine what colour it should be. eg. Insulator = 0, Isolated Conductor = 1, Touches  Top = 3, Touches Bottom = 5. That way you can track short circuits merely by looking for the bitwise logical or of two adjacent cells being equal to 7 (and you only ever need to look at nearest neighbours and of any conducting cells adjacent to them.

Comment: I sounds to me like you need to adapt a maze-solving algorithm.

Comment: @Martín Brown  if tried your algorithm but is much more slower than the implementations with disjoint sets i dont know if u can give me any clue of what have i done wrong

Comment: Perhaps you can simplify the search for short circuit since you know that the element that you just changed must be a member of the disjoint set that you seek. Also why isn't it sufficient to search just the top or bottom cells? - a short circuit will connect both sides together so it seems to me that you can save a factor of two there.

Comment: Please refactor your code to english language.